# python sum a array which length is arbitrary

Tags: python, arrays, sum, reduce

Sorry for a stupid question.
I want to sum a list. But length of list is not always bigger than 2
So `reduce` will fail if `len<2`

this is my code

```
score = [('xxx', 1), ('yyy', 2)]
if len(score) >=2:
    result = reduce((lambda x,y:x[1]+y[1]), score)
elif len(score)==1:
    result = score[0]
else:
    result = 0
```

is it possible to sum a array whenever length of list is bigger than 2 in a elegant way?

Comment: `result = score[0][1]`

Comment: That lambda function for the reduce makes no sense, this wouldn't work for any length. Now the simple `reduce(lambda total, cur: cur[1]+total, score, 0)` would.

Comment: @Voo thanks for teaching me, this really work. appreciate your help~~

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is `sum`:

```
result = sum(s[1] for s in score)
```